# How can I have a custom restart script for runit?

Tags: haproxy, runit

I'm using runit to manage an HAProxy and want to do a safe restart to reload a configuration file (specifically: `haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg  -sf $OLD_PROCESS_ID`). I figure that I could `run sv restart haproxy` and tried to add a custom script named `/etc/service/haproxy/restart`, but it never seems to execute. How do I have a special restart script? Is my approach even good here? How do I reload my config with minimal impact using runit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HAProxy runit service script

/etc/service/haproxy/run

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# runit haproxy
#

# forward stderr to stdout for use with runit svlogd
exec 2>&1

PID_PATH=/var/run/haproxy/haproxy.pid
BIN_PATH=/opt/haproxy/sbin/haproxy
CFG_PATH=/opt/haproxy/etc/haproxy.cfg

exec /bin/bash <<EOF
$BIN_PATH -f $CFG_PATH -D -p $PID_PATH

trap "echo SIGHUP caught; $BIN_PATH -f $CFG_PATH -D -p $PID_PATH -sf \\\$(cat $PID_PATH)" SIGHUP
trap "echo SIGTERM caught; kill -TERM \\\$(cat $PID_PATH) && exit 0" SIGTERM SIGINT

while true; do # Iterate to keep job running.
  sleep 1 # Wake up to handle signals
done
EOF
```

Graceful reload that keeps things up and running.

```
sv reload haproxy
```

Full stop and start.

```
sv restart haproxy
```

This solution was inspired by https://gist.github.com/gfrey/8472007

Comment: Please let me know if there are any problems. I just figured this one out and haven't yet really put it through it's paces.

Comment: The only real problem with it is the lack of logging, which can _probably_ be done by adding a line `exec 2>&1` before the `exec /bin/bash <<EOF` line. 
This should enable `svlogd` to pick it up.
Once you've done that, you can also add some `echo`s to those `trap`s

Comment: Thank you @LauriPiisang,  I was using this in conjunction with *consul-template* and had another problem where I was having the trap called so quickly as I was scaling in backends (up to 30 at once) that I would have up to 5 *haproxy*'s reading and writing to the pidsfile at the same time.  I ended up telling *consul-template* to ease up on how quickly it would restart *haproxy*.